# Splitting with Regex.Match

Tags: c#, regex, split

I've a string like "Colors: yellow, green, white".
I need to get an array ("yellow", "green", "white") from it and it needs to be done with one regex.

I'm trying to apply something like

```
var result = Regex.Match("Colors: green, white, yellow", @":(\s(?<result>.*?)(,|$))*");
```

what I get is that *result.Groups["result"]=="yellow"*

How can I get all the other colors? May be there's another way to do this?

Comment: is it a must to use regex? You can get an array easily by using split function anyway.

Comment: yep, there will be many regexps for different source strings, so it must be done in one step (ie. not firstly remove "Colors :" part and split by comma afterwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try result.Groups["result"].Captures

Answer (score 2):

This snippet will get you an array of colours from your `result` Match object.

```
string[] colours = result.Groups["result"].Captures
    .Cast<Capture>()
    .Select(c => c.Value)
    .ToArray();
```